# How to copy one Virtuoso database to another without admin rights?

Tags: replication, rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso

I am working on replicating my application's environments and one of the components is a `Virtuoso` `RDF` data store.  What I need to do is copy the entire database from one host to another.

I have found [these instructions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksDBMSBackupCrashDump) but they assume admin rights on the source to produce a dump. I only have admin rights on the target host.

Is there a way to easily copy an entire source database to a target easily without doing multiple `sparql` reads or at least with simple sparql that doesn't require knowing the data structure, if I am not an admin and can't do a dump from the source?

Comment: That reads an awful lot like "I want to steal someone's database. How can I do it?" Setting that aside... You can just copy the `virtuoso.db` and `virtuoso.ini` following a clean `checkpoint` and `shutdown`. For a full database relocation, this or the backup/dump/reload are the best ways to go. If these are really not possible... you'll need to explain more about why not, and what you *can* do, for anyone to give you useful advice. (ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: I have read access to the DB and can see every byte stored inside when I query using sparql.  I do not have access to the db and ini files as I am not an admin on the source. as far as "steal someone's db"...  I want to replicate the db so that I can have it locally on my laptop along with other (relational) databases that my application uses so that I can work on the app without internet connection, i.e. be on a sail boat or in the woods some place and working without connectivity...

Comment: e.g. for relational databases, I just read the schema from system tables, create my tables and constraints locally, then import each table data, then create foreign keys.  it works with every database.  i do it in `Python`. I am trying to do the same replication with Virtuoso, hoping it won't be nearly as complex as with SQL because it is essentially one big table with 3 fields, if my limited understanding of virtuoso is right

Comment: Internal RDF storage is not quite so simple as you imagine (4 columns, to start with -- Subject, Predicate, Object, Graph/Context)... The instructions you found are for a full Virtuoso DB dump -- not just RDF, but all SQL tables, WebDAV objects, etc. If you just want RDF dump of [one or multiple graphs](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfdumpandreloadgraphs/), you can use different tools -- but this sort of thing does typically require user (not necessarily *admin*) access to the filesystem.

Comment: You can use things like `CONSTRUCT` queries against the SPARQL endpoint through curl or web browser, to get RDF files in various serializations, which *may* deliver what you're after ... but far better to get temporary access to the current host, or to get an admin there to ship you the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a Virtuoso Database Document from one system to another, you can as long as you have a Virtuoso Database Server binary installed at the destination.

Your destination database (the copy) will include all data stored across Virtuoso SQL Relational, RDF Property Graph, and WebDAV storage realms.

Ideally, you should put the source Database is stable state before copying the virtuoso.db and virtuoso.ini files via a checkpoint or system shutdown (which includes a checkpoint).